# Showing that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show the following:

> Let $g$ be a continuous function of a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $f$ has this property: for each point $z \in D$, there is a disc $C$ centered at $z$ on which $g$ is constant. Conclude that $g$ is constant throughout $D$.

Here domain means nonempty, open, and connected and connected means that there is a polygonal line contained in the set which connects any two points. My strategy goes as follows:

Let $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ be two distinct points of $D$. Then showing $g(p_{1}) = g(p_{2})$ completes the proof. Since $D$ is a domain, there is a polygonal line connecting them contained entirely in $D$ and it suffices to show that they are joined by a single line segment (because the case where there are additional line segments can be handled by induction). So we know that there exists a disk $C_{p_{1}}$ centered at $p_{1}$ on which $g$ is constant. We can recover this disk to a sub-disk $C_{p_{1}}'$ which is centered at $p_{1}$ and contained entirely in $D$. Now from here I can choose a point $q_{1} \in C_{p_{1}}'$ that is ''closest'' to $p_{2}$ (since $C_{p_{1}}'$ is closed) and then repeat this process of finding neighborhoods contained in $D$ on which $g$ is constant-- and equal to $g(p_{1})$-- all the while getting closer to $p_{2}$.

Here is where I am stuck. While this process certainly gets us closer to $p_{2}$, it does not necessarily ensure that there is some $q_{n}$ for which the disk centered at $q_{n}$ on which $g$ is constant contains $p_{2}$. I believe that this does follow from continuity, but I am unsure how to use that hypothesis to move my disks far enough along to contain $p_{2}$.

Comment: Fix a point $p \in D$. Consider the two sets $A = \{ z \in D : g(z) = g(p)\}$ and $B = \{ z\in D : g(z) \neq g(p)\}$. What do you know about these two sets?

Comment: Well $D = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. $A = g^{-1}(\{ g(p)\})$, so it is closed since its the preimage of a closed set and so $B$ is open.

Comment: What does the assumption that $g$ is locally constant tell you about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The locally constant constraint implies that $A$ is open since for each point I can find a disk where $g$ is constant- which is then implies it is contained in $A$. We can then recover this to a open neighborhood?

Comment: What about $B$? What can you tell about $B$?

Comment: So you have a partition of $D$ into two disjoint open sets. Hence?

Comment: @DanielFischer thereby contradicting connected!

Comment: Not quite. By connectedness one of the two is empty.

Comment: @DanielFischer indeed. In my mind, I was assuming that $B \neq \emptyset$ in order to deduce a contradiction. I just did not convey that. Thank you for the help! The comments were the perfect amount of vague.

Comment: By the way, you can finish your start using a compactness argument. About each point on the segment, take a disk on which $g$ is constant. Take a finite subcover. Alternative: Parametrise the path as $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to D$. Let $s = \sup \{ t \in [0,1] : g\circ \gamma \text{ is constant on } [0,t]\}$. Take a disk around $\gamma(s)$ to see that $g\circ \gamma$ is constant on $[0,s]$, and that $s = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from rather general properties of topological spaces and continuous functions.

Assume $g \colon D \to X$ is as above, where $X$ is a topological space in which points are closed, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $p \in D$ and $r := g(p)$.

Now $\{r \} \subset X$ is a closed subset, so $p^{-1}(r)$ is a closed subset of $D$.
By the assumption above every point in $p^{-1}(r)$ has an open neighborhood contained in $D$, so this subset is also open. Thus $p^{-1}(r)$ is a connected component of $D$, and since $D$ is connected that implies $p^{-1}(r) = D$.